# Rails 5 - User specified CSS not working on Heroku with custom domain

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, heroku, cloudflare

I'd like to add a way for users to specify a few colors to be used on the site rather than the base ones from my core CSS. I've accomplished this via the code below, however it is not working in my Heroku hosted production environment, specifically the one with a custom domain and DNS routed through Cloudflare (i.e. it works on my-app.herokuapp.com but not www.my-custom-domain.com). If I open the custom CSS file directly in my browser (via the page source) and refresh it then the CSS is reflected on the site. Is this a Heroku limitation? Cloudflare? Is my approach less than ideal?

views/layouts/application.html.erb:

```
<html>
  <head>
    ...
    <%= stylesheet_link_tag 'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => 'reload' %>
    <% if the user is signed in and has selected custom colors %>
      <%= stylesheet_link_tag(application_custom_colors_path(format: :css), media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => 'reload' ) %>
    <% end %>
    ...
  </head>
</html>
```

application_controller.rb

```
def custom_colors
  @color1 = current_user.color1
  @color2 = current_user.color2
  respond_to do |format|
    format.css
  end
end
```

views/application/custom_colors.css.erb

```
body {
  color: <%= @color1 %>;
}
```

As I said above, this works on my local machine and deployed to Heroku using their standard my-app.herokuapp.com domain, however it ceases to work when using a custom domain via Cloudflare. Any guidance is much appreciated.

page source:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="/assets/application-3fac9a8b9a23a84ee912eb6f5438eff5514038c3646ef0a547ebb512994b6ca4.css" data-turbolinks-track="reload" />
<link rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="/application/custom_colors.css" data-turbolinks-track="reload" />
```

Comment: Do you have any errors in your browser console? Can you copy how exactly this row looks on Cloudflare domain (I mean html from your browser)

Comment: @AntonTkachov No console errors. I added the page source, which is identical between the my-app.herokuapp.com and www.mycustomdomain.com pages.

Comment: Have you checked your `www.mycustomdomain.com/application/custom_colors.css` url?

Comment: @AntonTkachov Yep, it pulls up fine, and if I make a color change and then refresh that file directly in the browser, the new color is reflected in the app. Weird.

Comment: Maybe it was cached?

Comment: @AntonTkachov I thought about caching but I just don't know how that works.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160190/discussion-between-antontkachov-and-cchandler81).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out Cloudflare caches all static content with certain extensions, including CSS and Javascript, by default. To get around this I added a Page Rule in my Cloudflare account to bypass the caching of `www.mycustomdomain.com/application/custom_colors.css`. More info [here](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/202775670-How-Do-I-Tell-Cloudflare-What-to-Cache-).